# Display custom tool tip in Jqplot Line chart?

Tags: jsf, tooltip, jqplot, linechart

For example I have plotted a line chart based on the date and number of students registered on a particular day on x and y axis respectively. When i mouse over to a particular point in the line chart i can view the tool tip displaying the x and y axis values. Instead I want to display the names of the students registered on that day when I mouse over to a particular point. Is there any solution for this problem? If there is no work around with Jqplot, please suggest me any other charts.. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [little example](http://jsfiddle.net/fwRSH/86/) I put together for you.

It uses the largely undocumented `tooltipContentEditor` property of the highlighter plugin:

```
         highlighter: {
            show: true,
            sizeAdjust: 7.5,
            tooltipContentEditor:tooltipContentEditor
         }
```

Where your data is predefined like:

```
      var students = [
          ['Bob','Mark','Dave'],
          ['Tim','Mike']
      ];

      var data = [students[0].length,students[1].length];          

      function tooltipContentEditor(str, seriesIndex, pointIndex, plot) {
          // display series_label, x-axis_tick, y-axis value
          return students[pointIndex].join(", ");
        }
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, The problem that I am facing is I have to get the names of the students dynamically by querying based on the date which the user hovers... So how could I get the names dynamically inside the javascript. Is there any solution that you could please suggest?

Comment: What do you mean by get them dynamically?  Are you making an ajax call to a database?

Comment: @user2239175, what have you tried?  You are asking me to help you with little to no details of what you want to do.  It would be pretty simply to make an AJAX call from the tooltipContentEditor function.  I'd worry about the delay, though, so better yet, why not store the students names in a global variable when the page loads as I've done above?